# Shear Mapping Question

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ and $W$ are linear spaces, how can we define a SHEAR linear mapping $T:V\to W$ ?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping).

Comment: I saw that link, but there is only a definition for $V=W$.

Comment: The concept of "shear" makes the most sense when $V=W$. I do not see how we could define a shear mapping unless $dim(V)=dim(W)$, which would use the same kind of matrix.